# File Upload in AngularJs Using MVC

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I have currently started on AngularJs, my requirement is to post the Files to MVC controller via AngularJs. Below is the code snippet.

In my View I have

```
 <input name="myFile" id="myFile" multiple type="file" ng-model="myFile" 
  upload-files/>
```

And this is my model,

```
    public class EmployeeDto
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public Nullable<int> DeptId { get; set; }
        public List<int> PrivilegeId { get; set; }

        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeePrivileges> EmployeePrivileges { get; set;}
        public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
        public byte[] EmpPhoto { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase[] File { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

You can see the property  HttpPostedFileBase[] File. I want to assign Uploaded files to this property through JSON, is it possible?

In my Controller.js

```
 var app = angular.module("EmpApp", []);

   //Directive for Upload Files
   app.directive('uploadFiles', function () {
   return {
     scope: true,        //create a new scope  
     link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.bind('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;

           //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element  
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                //emit event upward      
                scope.$emit("selectedFile", { file: files[i] });
             }
         });
      }
   };
 });

  app.controller("EmpCtlr", function ($scope, EmpService) {
    $scope.AddEmployee = function () {
    //  $scope.files = [];       
    if ($scope.Action == "Save") {
        var employee = {
            Id: $scope.Id,
            Name: $scope.EmpName,
            DateOfJoining: $scope.DOJ,
            DeptId: $scope.selectedDept,
            PrivilegeId: $scope.selectedPriv,
            IsActive: 1            
       };


        var addEmployee = EmpService.AddEmployeeSvc(employee);
        addEmployee.then(function (msg) {
            GetEmployees();
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting book records');
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

My Service.js.

```
this.AddEmployeeSvc = function (employee) {
            return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             params:employee,
             url: "Employee/AddEmployee",
             headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
             transformRequest: function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("myFile", Files);
            return formData;
          },
        })          
       };
```

My MVC Controller Method

```
     [HttpPost]
     public void AddEmployee(EmployeeDto employee)
     {
      //I will have to say  Request.Form for all input elements but how to 
      // get in employee object


         //var _data = Request.Form["properties"];

         //This is working
        var photo =HttpContext.Request.Files.Count

     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Upload file using AngularJS in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286152/how-to-upload-file-using-angularjs-in-mvc)

Comment: you can use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) if it's not a requirement that you right this from scratch

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.
Ramesh, the thread you shared really worked.
But one more thing is I want to pass the other data as well.  In my question I have this EmployeeDto class whose object is initialized in the AngularController.
In my MVC Controller I have something like this

       public void AddEmployee(EmployeeDto employee)
        {
                 // This really works but how to get data in employee object
                 Request.Form["properties"]
                // This is for file it's working
               HttpContext.Request.Files
        }

Comment: Hello All,

I have made necessary edits in my question after looking into Ramesh's answer, please take a look.